# onOptionsItemSelected return incorrect ID

Tags: android, menu

(Newbe)

When I click on a menu the above method returns an ID from the first menu, not the one I clicked. If I check for the Title Condensed of the menu it is correct.

```
int id = item.getItemId();   //returns id of an incorrect menu
String Title = (String) item.getTitleCondensed();  //this returns the correct title.
```

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: what do you mean by *The first menu*? Is this a submenu?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. Generated files from the build are not properly updated.

I got the same effect if i reordered the menu items in the xml...build and surprise. Clicking on menu brings other codes than expected.

Do a clean and try again

Comment: This just happened to me - the cleaning helped me... Strange - but thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You should have set each menu item a unique ID in onCreateOptionsMenu and onCreateContextMenu.

For example:

```
    public static final int CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE = Menu.FIRST;
    public static final int CONTEXT_MENU_EDIT = CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE + 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, 
                    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

            menu.add(0, CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE, 1, R.string.delete);
            menu.add(0, CONTEXT_MENU_EDIT, 2, R.string.edit);
    }

    // And then

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            switch(item.getItemId()) {

            case CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE:
                    // Delete item
                    break;

            case CONTEXT_MENU_EDIT:
                    // Edit item
                    break;
            }
    }
```

The same is for onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected. You should have a unique constant for every menu option.

Added:

Didn't you check out [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)?
The idea is the same. You should set different ids in `menu.xml`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:id="@+id/new_game"
              android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_game"
              android:title="@string/new_game" />
        <item android:id="@+id/help"
              android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
              android:title="@string/help" />
    </menu>
```

And then use those ids in `onOptionsItemSelected`:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.new_game:
            newGame();
            return true;
        case R.id.help:
            showHelp();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Check out these code blocks from official Android Menu tutorial and compare to your own code. You could also publish your `menu.xml`, `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected` so it would be easy to figure out your problem.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply.  I should have mentioned that my menu is from a menu.xml file so I do not assign the id's, they are system generated eg 3124655 or similar. And it is the system Id returned that is incorrect.

Comment: I have added resources part to the answer. You can also publish your `menu.xml`, `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected` so it would be easy to figure out your problem.

Comment: Hi, The Tutorial is exactly where I started. My menu looks like this: